# Django: Conflicting behaviour in views

Tags: python, django, wiki

I have a wiki app which has the storing, saving, editing abilities. when I create a wiki page it gets stored perfectly and the view_page view does not have any problem in fetching its data from database and displaying it in the browser.
But the problem arises when i click the edit button and it goes in the edit_page view, which isn't fetching the data. It fetches the title, but it isn't fetching the contents and raises an Article.DoesNotExist exception.

here are the two views:

```
def view_page(request):
    if "title" in request.GET and request.GET["title"]:
        article_name = request.GET["title"]
        try:
            article = Article.objects.get(title=article_name)
        except Article.DoesNotExist:
            return render_to_response("search_page.html", {"error": "page doesn't exist"})
        return render_to_response("view_page.html", {"title": article.title, "content": article.content})
    else:
        return render_to_response("search_page.html", {"error": "page doesn't exist."})


def edit_page(request):
    c = {}
    c.update(csrf(request))
    if "title" in request.GET:
        article_name = request.GET["title"]
        try:
            article = Article.objects.get(title=article_name)
            content = article.content
        except Article.DoesNotExist:
            content = ""

        c["title"] = article_name
        c["content"] = content
        return render_to_response("edit_page.html", c)

        def save_page(request):
            if request.method == 'POST':

                if "title" in request.POST and "content" in request.POST and request.POST["title"]:

                    c = {}
                    c.update(csrf(request))
                    try:
                        article = Article.objects.get(title=request.POST["title"])
                        article.content = request.POST["content"]
                    except Article.DoesNotExist:
                        article = Article(request.POST["title"], request.POST["content"])
                        article.save()
                        return HttpResponseRedirect("/view_page/?title="+request.POST["title"])
                    return render_to_response("create_page.html", c)
```

here is my model:

```
class Article(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(primary_key=True, unique=True, max_length=20)
    content = models.TextField(blank=True)
```

Comment: the edit_page displays the title but the contents are not being fetched for whatever reason. If I again use the view_page view, it displays both title and content. I dont know what and where the problem is.

Comment: Can we see the code for the view where you save the content and title to your object?

Comment: added the save_page view.

Comment: Can you post the code for your templates?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the problem and I only now found the time to post it here but better late than never, huh.
anyways, the problem was in retrieval procedure of the data from the db. when I store the data it saves the strings without the quotes i.e ''. and the conflict was that in the view_page my query requests for article with title, say, TITLE. but in the edit_page, the query requested the article with title, 'TITLE'. (note the quotes). and hence the error.
the reason why the page displayed the title nonetheless, was that I was storing the title passed as argument to the view in the response dictionary and not the values fetched by the database.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the problem might be in the `try` block of the try-catch section of the `save_page()` view, try something like:

```
def save_page(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':

        if "title" in request.POST and "content" in request.POST and request.POST["title"]:

            c = {}
            c.update(csrf(request))
            try:
                article = Article.objects.get(title=request.POST["title"])
                article.content = request.POST["content"]
                article.save()
            except Article.DoesNotExist:
                article = Article(request.POST["title"], request.POST["content"])
                article.save()
                return HttpResponseRedirect("/view_page/?title="+request.POST["title"])
            return render_to_response("create_page.html", c)
```

Previously, if the article previously existed, it was not being saved after it's content was updated.

**Edit:** You can try debugging the `edit_page()` view, using something like:

```
def edit_page(request):
    c = {}
    c.update(csrf(request))
    if "title" in request.GET:
        article_name = request.GET["title"]
        try:
            article = Article.objects.get(title=article_name)
            content = article.content
            print "article: %s retrieved from database" % article_name
        except Article.DoesNotExist:
            print "article: %s not found in database" % article_name
            content = ""

        c["title"] = article_name
        c["content"] = content
        return render_to_response("edit_page.html", c)
```

If you are using `./manage.py runserver` the debug messages should appear intermixed with the http requests, if the database is retrieving the article correctly, there must be an issue with the template.

Comment: i added the 'article.save()' command but the problem still persists.

Comment: this change saves the data AFTER the edit has been made. but that wasn't the actual problem. problem was that the content wasn't being fetched from the database. data gets committed, view_page fetches it, but edit_page cannot.

Comment: @ZaidTariq I added an edit about debugging the edit view, does this help?